# How to change this.state status during authentication? Firebase + React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I use react-router and Firebase for authentication. For this function **onButtonClick** from file **SignIn** must change state in **App.js** for true. How to do this? Maybe there are some other ways except my idea?

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
 ....
import firebase from './firebase/firebase.js';

class App extends Component {

state = {
      signedInStatus : false
};

render(){
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        this.state.signedInStatus
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/signIn' />
    )} />
  )
  return(
    <div>
      <Header signedInStatus={this.state.signedInStatus} />
    <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn}/>
        <Route path="/signIn" component={SignIn}/>
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
    </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Second file ensure work with inputing information for getting to user cabinet.
SignIn.js :

```
    import...
    class SignIn extends Component {
    state = {
          email: '',
          password: '',
    };

    onButtonClick = (event) =>{
      event.preventDefault();
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
           .then((user) => {
             this.props.history.push('/home')
             console.log("ok")  /// here i want add something to change 
           })                   /// this.state.signedIn for true in App
           .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            alert(error);
          });
    }

    onChangeInputEmail = (event) => {
      this.setState({email: event.target.value})
    };

    onChangeInputPassword = (event) => {
      this.setState({password: event.target.value})
    };

    render(){
      return (
            ...
      )
    };

    export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define a method to update state for App.js then you can pass props to components as following

```
<Route
  path='/signIn'
  render={(props) => <SignIn {...props} changeSignedInStatus={this.changeSignedInStatus} />}
/>
```

Comment: Welcome my frnd happy to help